# Changing filenames that have special characters in bash

Tags: python, bash, perl, batch-rename

We are running a Ubuntu server that automatically FTPs files from a customer and these files, lately, are showing up now as ...
'file.csv;'
'file2.csv;

I have been trying, with no luck, to formulate bash and Python solutions with no luck. I am just trying to strip out the single quotes and semicolons and keep what's left.  This doesn't have to be bash, it could be python or even perl. I included code below of what isn't working. I can't even seem to get a directory listing. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

```
for i in \'* 
    do
    echo $i
done
```

Note: corrected code to remove errant $echo'

Comment: use https://www.shellcheck.net/ . If you paste your code with the right shebang, it tells you that you're trying to use `echo` as a variable, which is probably not want you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `find ... -exec rename` like so:

```
find . -name "*[;']*" -exec rename "tr/';//d" {} \;
```

Example:

```
# Create example input files:
$ touch "f'o''o'" "b;a;;r;" "b';a;'';z;'"

# Build the command by first confirming that `find` finds them all:
$ find . -name "*[;']*"                            
./f'o''o'
./b';a;'';z;'
./b;a;;r;

# Find and rename them, one by one:
$ find . -name "*[;']*" -exec rename "tr/';//d" {} \;

# Confirm that rename worked as expected:
$ ls -1rt | tail -n 3                                
foo
bar
baz
```

You can also do a bulk rename for speed using `xargs`, such as

```
find ... -print0 | xargs -0 ...
```

but in your case I assume that renaming the files one by one is fast enough.

---

The command-line utility `rename` comes in many flavors. Most of them should work for this task. I used the [`rename`](https://github.com/ap/rename) version 1.601 by Aristotle Pagaltzis. To install `rename`, simply download its Perl script and place into `$PATH`. Or install `rename` using `conda`, like so:

```
conda install rename
```

Comment: you can rename them then do the job https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.geeksforgeeks.org/rename-multiple-files-using-python/amp/

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
filesInDirectory = os.listdir(Path)

for filename in filesInDirectory:
    if "'" in filename:
        filename.replace("'", "")
    elif ";" in filename:
        filename.replace(";", "") 
    elif ("'" and ";") in filename:
        filename.replace("'", "")
        filename.replace(";", "")
```

Using Python

Answer (score 0):

You can start by trying this pyhon 3 script. I tested it only in Windows though.

```
import os

folder = ""
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(folder, topdown=False):
    for fn in files:
        path_to_file = os.path.join(root, fn)
        if "'" in fn or ";" in fn:
            print('Removing special characters from file: ' + fn)
            new_name = fn.replace("'", '').replace(";", '') 
            os.rename(path_to_file, os.path.join(root, new_name))
```